# Why is `foo in list` returning false even though the arrayListOf contains it?

Tags: kotlin

I was trying out this piece of code in Kotlin which I wrote out(I am a beginner in Kotlin). I expected to receive "True" however I received "False" even though `listo` contains it. This is my code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    class product(var product: String, var productName: String)
    val listo = arrayListOf(
            product("shirt", "yoyo")
    )
    val testing = product("shirt", "yoyo")
    if (testing in listo) {
        println("True")
    } else {
        println("False")
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `product` class doesn't override the `equals` method so it's doing an object instance comparison and the two lists contains different objects.

You can declare `product` with `data class product(...` which auto generates the `equals` method which will compare the two string properties meaning `listo` will contain `testing`. It also generates a bunch of other convenient methods.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html